# Generating ragged edges in CSS

Tags: css, html

I'm currently using images and I'd like to know if theres any css library/way of generating these ragged edges

larger sized image: (using png's for the top and bottom parts of the content)
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/linS1.png
[image]

thanks !

edit: I noticed there's voting on closing this question but I'd like to keep it open for the rest of the day in case more solns are provided.

Comment: I don't know about CSS, but maybe you could try SVG? [*link*](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/default.asp)

Comment: I will give that a try tomorrow and get back at you here. Ty

Comment: use photoshop create a `PNG` image as background, and repeat it

Comment: something like [this?](http://jsfiddle.net/yKPe9/3/)

Comment: @Cattla I'm already using pngs (as in the image above ^) but I wanted to see if I could do it fully through css as I wanted to have rough edges all around the white areas

Comment: @jbutler483 The edges I'm trying to generate are more random and wavy though. Appreciate the effort though and I'll try and see if I can obtain something from it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `svg`'s `filter`s to get a similar effect.

```css
body {
  background: tan;
}
svg {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
p {
  color: peru;
  padding: 45px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">
  <defs>
    <filter id="filter" height="1.4" width="1.4">
      <feTurbulence baseFrequency="0.12" numOctaves="2" type="fractalNoise" result="result1" />
      <feDisplacementMap in2="result1" scale="99" result="result2" xChannelSelector="R" in="SourceGraphic" />
      <feComposite in2="result2" in="SourceGraphic" operator="atop" result="fbSourceGraphic" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <rect fill="saddlebrown" filter="url(#filter)" width="500" height="500" x="0" y="0" />
  <foreignObject width="500" height="500">
    <div>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        <br />
        <br />Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem
        quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam
        eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit
        qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
      </p>
    </div>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is somewhat the closest, but I'll still go with using images I guess, they just look much smoother.

Answer (score 11):

I believe things have progressed since this originally posted in 2014. The year is now 2017, and I have used CSS to create the look of rough / torn edges. See code example here. I am sure with more work I could make it more convincing... but I like the results this is giving me for my purposes.

```
clip-path: polygon(3% 0, 7% 1%, 11% 0%, 16% 2%, 20% 0, 23% 2%, 28% 2%, 32% 1%, 35% 1%, 39% 3%, 41% 1%, 45% 0%, 47% 2%, 50% 2%, 53% 0, 58% 2%, 60% 2%, 63% 1%, 65% 0%, 67% 2%, 69% 2%, 73% 1%, 76% 1%, 79% 0, 82% 1%, 85% 0, 87% 1%, 89% 0, 92% 1%, 96% 0, 98% 3%, 99% 3%, 99% 6%, 100% 11%, 98% 15%, 100% 21%, 99% 28%, 100% 32%, 99% 35%, 99% 40%, 100% 43%, 99% 48%, 100% 53%, 100% 57%, 99% 60%, 100% 64%, 100% 68%, 99% 72%, 100% 75%, 100% 79%, 99% 83%, 100% 86%, 100% 90%, 99% 94%, 99% 98%, 95% 99%, 92% 99%, 89% 100%, 86% 99%, 83% 100%, 77% 99%, 72% 100%, 66% 98%, 62% 100%, 59% 99%, 54% 99%, 49% 100%, 46% 98%, 43% 100%, 40% 98%, 38% 100%, 35% 99%, 31% 100%, 28% 99%, 25% 99%, 22% 100%, 19% 99%, 16% 100%, 13% 99%, 10% 99%, 7% 100%, 4% 99%, 2% 97%, 1% 97%, 0% 94%, 1% 89%, 0% 84%, 1% 81%, 0 76%, 0 71%, 1% 66%, 0% 64%, 0% 61%, 0% 59%, 1% 54%, 0% 49%, 1% 45%, 0% 40%, 1% 37%, 0% 34%, 1% 29%, 0% 23%, 2% 20%, 1% 17%, 1% 13%, 0 10%, 1% 6%, 1% 3%);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is only possible with images, and is perfectly fine to do with images. If it's the extra roundtrip of the image you're worried about - it's easy to embed this into your CSS so it's concise and fast. You can use any image type you prefer for the actual image - for this specific purpose PNG or SVG are the most probable candidates (PNG is easier to tile actually).

[Read this article on embedding images as Data URIs in your CSS](http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/).

[Here's a good online tool to create Date URIs](http://dataurl.net/#dataurlmaker).

Comment: thanks, that was a good read. In the image above, I have it done with pngs but I wanted to see if I could create the same effect with css so that I can have the rough edges all around the content ( so make it a border effect ).

Comment: For that part specifically: look at the border-image properties. Support is sketchy right now but good to keep on the radar.

Comment: [See browser support here on CSS3 `border-image`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-image).

Comment: I see, not too bad but could be better.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use SVG. You could easily have those exact shapes in Illustrator/Sketch and export the SVG file from there.